# symfony 2 form display default value

Tags: forms, symfony, default-value

I'm working with Symfony 2.0.14 and I would like to display the default value in my form template.

Well a FormType is bound to an entity, when I want to add extra field, I know the option property_path = false allow to add non-entity fields, right ?

When I m in the opposite case, I want to set an entity field without a form field.
Ok I just have to give a default entity to "createForm".

Howewver how can I render it in my template form ?

---

Controller code :

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $game = new Game();

    $local = new Role();
    $visitor = new Role();
    $local->setType('LOCAL');
    $visitor->setType('VISITOR');
    $game->addRole($local);
    $game->addRole($visitor);

    $form = $this->createForm(new GameType(), $game);
```

GameType code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('teams', 'collection', array( 'type' => new RoleType()));
}
```

RoleType code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
   $builder->add('type', 'text');  // <= I would like read only for end-User 
   $builder->add('score', 'integer');
```

form template :

```
{% for role in form.teams %}
        <li>
            <div class="role-team">
                {{ role.type }} {# WRONG way, how to do ?  #}
                {{ form_row(role.score) }}
            </div>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to display your entity field value (without passing the entire entity to the view) you can print it with:

```
{{ form.vars.value.type }}
```

(assuming your role entity has type property).

**EDIT**: i realized you're inside the loop. Try figuring out the right property path using:

```
{% for role in form.teams %}
    {% debug role %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks first one is the good one !!
`{{ role.vars.value.type }}` do the job as role is a FormView also.

Tips, to enable debug I added to config.yml :
`services:
    twig.extension.debug:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug
        tags:
             - { name: 'twig.extension' }`